# fgetc() doesn't work properly in function

Tags: c, file, io

I am trying to read a text file, character by character, with `fgetc()` function but it does not show any output. It is a school project and it is still in very very simple way just to test the functionality of the program.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void fn1(FILE *f);
void fn9(FILE *fp, char, char);

int main() {
  FILE *fp = fopen("text.txt", "r");
  if (fp == NULL) {
    perror("Error: ");
    exit(1);
  }
  fn1(fp);
  fn9(fp, '0', '9');

  fclose(fp);
  return 0;
}

void fn1(FILE *f) {
  int num, sum = 0, count = 0;

  while (fscanf(f, "%d", &num) == 1) {
    if (num > 0) {
      sum += num;
      count++;
    }
  }
  printf("the avg of positive nums is %.2f", (float) sum / count);
}

void fn9(FILE *fp, char m, char n) {
  int ch;
  int count1 = 0, count2 = 0;

  while ((ch = fgetc(fp)) != EOF) {
    if (ch == m)
      count1++;
    if (ch == n)
      count2++;
    printf("%c", ch);
    if (ferror(fp))
      break;
  }

  printf("\n%c is seen %d times", m, count1);
  printf("\n%c is seen %d times", n, count2);

  fclose(fp);
}
```

The file's content that I test is:

```
      90
      16
      -34
      100
```

Comment: Please present more context. How is the function called, what does the surrounding code look like?

Comment: `printf ( "%c", ch );` expects a `char` argument not `int` and may be the victim of endianness... but "does not show *any* output" is strange.

Comment: @WeatherVane Actually `%c` expects an `int` when used with `printf`. `scanf` is a different story.

Comment: Now can you also give an example data file for us to see :)

Comment: It seems that your `fn1` will scan the whole file, after which there are no characters left for the `fn9` to read. You can use `fseek` to reset the file position to the start, if you intend to scan the file twice.

Comment: Yes, after adding fseek() now it works correctly.

Comment: Minor: `if (ferror(fp))
      break;` serves no purpose here.  Had the error flag been set the prior `fgetc(fp)` would have returned `EOF`.  Still nice to consider that input errors do occur.

Answer (score 0):

After fn(fp) return, fp will point to the last location in the file. It needs to be reset to the start of file before fn9 is called. Use fseek to point fp to the start of file and it should work :)